# Excel depended data validation translated to Google Sheets

Tags: excel, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to use depended data validation with the Indirect() method as a range in Google Sheets? I imported an excel sheet with this function into Google Sheets and the sheet stopped working.

Comment: You may refer with this [tutorial](https://productivityspot.com/dependent-drop-list-google-sheets/). There is a direction to enter the formula `=INDIRECT(D3)` that would list all the items from the category selected in Drop Down 1. This is dynamic and if you change the drop down in cell D3 from Fruits to Vegetable, the list would change and show the list of vegetables. You  may also check this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aQrggyFvSXs;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Amac%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) that has a sample script.

Comment: posting my comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

https://productivityspot.com/dependent-drop-list-google-sheets/

you need to write the indirect function in a separate cell and then select the results of the function as your range for the dependent data validation drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [tutorial](https://productivityspot.com/dependent-drop-list-google-sheets/). There is a direction to enter the formula `=INDIRECT(D3)` that would list all the items from the category selected in Drop Down 1. This is dynamic and if you change the drop down in cell D3 from Fruits to Vegetable, the list would change and show the list of vegetables. You  may also check this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aQrggyFvSXs;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Amac%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) that has a sample script.